# CPPCheck printing invalid characters in output

Tags: c++, cppcheck

I am running cppcheck on the following piece of code

```
bool  bsIsBigEndian( void )
{
    return (((const int*)"\0\x1\x2\x3\x4\x5\x6\x7")[0] & 255) != 0;
}
```

with the command below

```
cppcheck --template={file};{line};{severity};{message};{id} --enable=style,performance,portability file.cpp
```

Output

Prints in 
[image]

I have tried --platform option but still same result.
How can I get rid of invalid characters ?

Comment: cppcheck is an old tool, and it fails on lots of things - just skip those errors or warnings

Comment: I do not understand what sort of output you are getting from cppcheck. You should get a well defined output, with statistics relating to the check. Can you post the full output please?

Comment: Seems to be `[test.cpp:3]: (style) Condition '(((const int*)"")[0]&255)!=0' is always false`. Seems like a cppcheck bug, but one that doesn't make the error message unusable. I mean, it printed unprintable characters, but that's non-important as it also provides context like a line number.

Comment: @RannLifshitz: Added output image

Comment: @xfix: You are right about the trivial nature of message as we have the line number already, but I use the error message further in my code and it gives me error due to invalid characters.

Comment: Can't you just use valid characters in the code?  (`"\01234567"` would be just as useful for this test).

Answer (score 1):

Your code has [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/736054).

You are casting a `const char *` to `const int *` which may (and will, because it's a string constant and the compiler likely won't bother aligning it) have different alignment. Your code can be fixed as such.

```
bool bsIsBigEndian() {
    const char *text = "\0\x1\x2\x3\x4\x5\x6\x7";
    int value;
    std::memcpy(&value, text, sizeof value);
    return (value & 255) != 0;
}
```

`memcpy` ignores alignment issues, and this is correct as long `int` is 8 bytes long or smaller, on most platforms it is 4 bytes long.

Also it's possible to get rid of a string constant by writing `const char text[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};` instead.

Comment: I have problem running cppcheck on the above piece of code. So the code may be incorrect. I am more worried about the output of cppcheck

Comment: @pranayjain I mean, this is a bug in cppcheck. [Report the issue to its developer.](https://trac.cppcheck.net/)